# How to play once a section/range of an AKAppleSequencer

Tags: audiokit

### What I want to achieve

For example, I have a sequence of length 12.0 (beats)
and I want to play once the range 4.0-8.0 (Not including any note that starts at 8.0)

### Solution 1 - Using Callback

I have tried

- I use `seq.setTime(4.0)`
- `seq.play()`
- adding a `AKCallbackInstrument`, and add a note at the desired range end (`position: 8.0`)
- In the callback, I can `seq.stop()`
- But the actually stop is occurring at something like 4.082635.
- I can already hear the note that starts at 4.0

#### Awkward solutions

- I might be able to MUTE all notes which are not in my range...
- I can set the callback note to `position: 7.9` (-:

### Solution 2 - Using Loop

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55161566/how-to-set-a-loop-not-at-the-end-of-track-using-audiokit-sequencer) which says this is problematic

### Solution 3

A robust solution would be to create a new `AKAppleSequencer` , and copy to it all the notes in the desired range.

but that's an overkill, isn't it?

Comment: Did you ever work out an answer to this? I have the same question.